# Nuxt.js createPersistedState using Middleware

Tags: nuxt.js

I have already setup the createdPersistedState based on github https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate

plugins/localStorage.js

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

export default ({store}) => {
  createPersistedState({
      key: 'vuex',
      paths: ['local']

  })(store)
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
plugins:[
  { src: '~/plugins/localStorage.js', ssr: false }
  ],
```

middleware/auth.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default function ({ store, params }) {

    return axios.post( process.env.baseApi + '/login', {
            email: 'example2@juanmerkado.com',
            password: '12345678'
        })
          .then(response => {
              //How to save it in createPersistedState or How can I do it here?
              store.dispatch('token', response.data.token)
            })
}
```

How to save it in localStorage using createdPersistedSate in middleware/auth.js?

Comment: It should work automatically. Vuex state will be saved to localstorage on every state change

Comment: @Aldarund I tried it but it's not working... It's not in the localStorage and the Vuex doesn't persist. thanks

Comment: and what is in your action? Did u actually set your token to state?

Comment: it works now... thanks..

Comment: `import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

export default ({store}) => {
  createPersistedState({
      
  })(store)
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

export default ({store}) => {
  createPersistedState({
    ...
  })(store)
}
```

Just remove this one

```
key: 'vuex',
paths: ['local']
```